# Telerik MVC Grid: Collection Inside Column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using Telerik's MVC Grid in my project which really is good. Unfortunately I am stuck at last.. The problem is that I want to show a collection inside a column. The collection is a property of my user model. Here is the sample code:

```
{...}    
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(u => u.Id).Title("No.").Width(100);
        columns.Bound(u => u.UserName).Title("User Name");
        columns.Bound(u => u.CompanyName).Title("Company Adı");
        columns.Template(u =>
            {
                foreach(var item in u.Roles)
                {

                }
            }).Title("Roller");
        columns.Command(commands => 
            {                    
                commands.Custom("viewDetails")
                .Text("Detail")
                .DataRouteValues(route => route.Add(o => o.Id).RouteKey("UserAccountId"))
                .Ajax(false)
                .Action("UserAccountRead", "Account");
                commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.ImageAndText);
            })
        .Width(200);
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(10))
    .Localizable("en-EN")
    ) 
{...}
```

In the foreach loop I've tried many things to display user roles, but haven't succeed.

```
@item.Name
I Got : Error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement

@:<text>@item.Name</text>
I Got: ; required
```

And so on... What should I write as a statement for just making the column to show user roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a ReadOnly property to your model which returns a simplified formatted text for you. for example you :

```
   partial class MyModel{
       public string RolesAsString
       {
          get{
                string result="";
                foreach(var item in this.Roles)
                {
                     result += string.format("{0},",item);
                }
                return result.trim(",");

          }
       }


   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Mahmoud. I also solved the problem with: `columns.Template(
                @<ul> 
                @foreach (var role in item.Roles) 
                { 
                    <li>@role.Name</li> 
                } 
                </ul>)
            .Title("Roller");`

Comment: But your solution makes problem in ajax call-backs(if you have any).